# Dynamic create a png image on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, png

How do I create a png image from text in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to save a view as an image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's covered in one of the first lectures in this term of Stanford's free iPhone programming course. There's a [video](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-development-winter-2010/id384233225) and PDF notes.

Basically, you can create a `UIImage` and use its graphics context to draw into it, then save a PNG representation of the image.

Comment: There is more than one video, so you may want to specify which Lecture it is.